# Java 8 Hash Map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a map `Map<String, List<Double>` and I would like to find the maximum (or minimum) value in all of the lists. 
The function should return the maximum (or minimum) value and the key belonging to that value.

The signature may be

`public static Pair<String,Double> getKeyValue(Map<String, List<Double>> map, BinaryOperator<Double> function)`

which gets the map and the function `Double::max` or `Double::min`

How can i implement this efficiently (and beautifully) using java 8, stream api ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `BinaryOperator` is not a good specification for that task, it is straight-forward to use in a reduction to produce the appropriate value, e.g. minimum or maximum, however it is not suitable for returning an associated value like the `Map`’s key value. Using it this way implies that the implementation has to perform additional operations to find out, what the `BinaryOperator` actually did in order to select the correct key value during the reduction. Even worse, it can’t guaranty that the `BinaryOperator` does something that allows to perform this kind of reduction, e.g. the operator might return a value which is neither of its arguments.

For such a task, a `Comparator` is the better choice as it is designed for specifying an ordering and perform related operations like finding maximum and minimum. An implementation might look like this:

```
public static Pair<String,Double> getMinimumKeyValue(
    Map<String, List<Double>> map, Comparator<Double> function) {

    return map.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e->new Pair<>(e.getKey(), e.getValue().stream().min(function).get()))
        .min(Comparator.comparing(Pair::getRight, function)).get();
}
```

It is named `getMinimumKeyValue` as it will return the minimum key/value pair when you pass in `Comparator.naturalOrder()`.

But you can get the maximum as well by passing `Comparator.reverseOrder()`.

And it’s easy to modify to support a broader range of use cases:

```
public static <K,V> Pair<K,V> getMinKeyValue(
    Map<K, ? extends Collection<V>> map, Comparator<? super V> function) {

    return map.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e->new Pair<>(e.getKey(), e.getValue().stream().min(function).get()))
        .min(Comparator.comparing(Pair::getRight, function)).get();
}
```

This still works for getting a `Pair<String,Double>` out of a `Map<String, List<Double>>` but can do a lot more…

Answer (score 4):

You can try this :

```
public static Pair<String,Double> getKeyValue(Map<String,List<Double>> map,
        BinaryOperator<Double> function) {
        return map.entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> new Pair<String,Double>(e.getKey(),e.getValue().stream().reduce(function).get()))
            .reduce((p1,p2) -> function.apply(p1.getValue(),p2.getValue()).equals(p1.getValue()) ? p1 : p2)
            .get();
}
```

**Explanation :**

First, you associate each `Entry<String,List<Double>>` to a `Pair<String,Double>` where the value is the min (or max) of the list and the key remains the same, then you compare each `Pair<String,Double>` to find the one which has the lowest (or highest) value.

Comment: You're using `==` on boxed `Double`s, which seems unlikely to work as expected.  I'd tend to try to move away from the `BinaryOperator<Double>` approach and prefer a `Comparator`....

Comment: That's right, but I'll just change the test to `a.equals(b)` to fix it. Thanks for noticing that !

Comment: I cannot really read this. Perhaps it’s the syntax, the missing pair literals, whatever, but I had less problems reading Haskell. In general, the functional approach is often much less readable than the plain old style in Java.

Comment: Java functional style is a bit verbose compared to other languages fully designed to integrate functional programming. You are right about a missing tuple syntax in Java that would enable to make this code much clearer.

Comment: Gah!  Don't use Optional.get here, it will throw if the map is empty.  Use one of the safe methods like ifPresent, orElse, or orElseThrow.